# How to reach other project's resources from spring applicationContext?

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsf, maven

I have a project named fc-jsf. This project's spring context refers to an other spring context named Beans.xml in the fc-bus project. I have fc-bus as project dependency for fc-jsf.

I import the Beans.xml like this:

```
<import resource="classpath*:com/fc/spring/Beans.xml" />
```

Its working, but it says that the fc-jsf project can't see the properties declared in Beans.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>com/fc/properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The exception is:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/com/fc/properties/database.properties]
```

How to reach the database.properties without copying the properties file to the fc-jsf project?

edit: theese are maven projects, database.properties is in fc-bus -> src/main/resurces/com/fc folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the properties like

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:com/fc/properties/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

otherwise it doesn't know which package it should use it from

Answer (score 0):

Try with  `<value>classpath*:database.properties</value>`